# Find the angle of intersection of the plane $4x+4y−1z=0$ with the plane $−4x−2y+3z=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the angle of intersection in radians of the plane $4x+4y−1z=0$ with the plane $−4x−2y+3z=0$.

Attempt:

Write $\overrightarrow{n_1} = (4,4,-1)$ and $\overrightarrow{n_2} = (-4, -2, 3)$ and then $\displaystyle \theta = \cos^{-1}\Big(\frac{\overrightarrow{n_1}\cdot\overrightarrow{n_2}}{|\overrightarrow{n_1}|\overrightarrow{n_2}|}\Big)=\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{-27}{|\sqrt{33}|\sqrt{29}|}\big)$.

However, this was the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps they wanted the acute angle instead of the obtuse angle. Make the dot product positive first:
$$
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{|-27|}{\sqrt{33}\sqrt{29}}\right)
\approx 0.5099 \text{ rad}
$$

Comment: It seems as if they did want the acute angle, however it was not specified. Thank you, and how does adding absolute value to the numerator make something an acute angle?

Comment: The range of $y = \cos^{-1}(x)$ is $[0,\pi]$. The acute portion of this range is attained when $x \in (0, 1)$.